# How to display a list of objects as a JList in java swing?

Tags: java, swing, object, arraylist, jlist

We are asked to build a system in Java Swing no drag and drop and I cannot understand how to display a list of objects in a `JList`.
I have a GUI class that creates a JFrame, JPanel, and an empty JList as well as a logic class with list of objects, which can be accessed via `logic.studentsList`.
I need to create more student objects via fields and display them in my JList and add to the existing `studentsList` (which is of type `ArrayList<Students>`).
Should I declare my `JList` as `JList` object type `Students`? I can't find information of how to connect JList with object list.
My only idea is to create new Student object from input fields data and pass it on to `logic.stundentsList`. But how to display it also in GUI as a JList?

Comment: Why a `JList`?  Why not a `JTable`, which is designed to display a table of rows and columns?  If you insist on using a `JList`, create a `JPanel` to display one and only one Student and place multiple instances of that student `JPanel` in a `JList`.

Comment: Please see [ask].

Answer (score 3):

1. Create a list of objects that you want to display.
2. Create a DefaultListModel object to store the objects in the list.
3. Create a JList object and set its model to the DefaultListModel.
4. Add the JList to a JScrollPane to allow for scrolling if the list is
   long.
5. Add the JScrollPane to a container such as a JFrame or JPanel to
   display the JList.

```
public class Example extends JFrame {
    
    public Example() {
        // Create a list of strings
        List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
        items.add("Item 1");
        items.add("Item 2");
        items.add("Item 3");
        
        // Create a DefaultListModel to store the strings
        DefaultListModel<String> listModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
        for (String item : items) {
            listModel.addElement(item);
        }
        
        // Create a JList and set its model to the DefaultListModel
        JList<String> jList = new JList<>(listModel);
        
        // Add the JList to a JScrollPane to allow for scrolling
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(jList);
        
        // Add the JScrollPane to a container such as a JFrame or JPanel
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(scrollPane);
        add(panel);
        
        // Set the JFrame properties
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Example");
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```